allow moderated list question
I'm aware that some of you won't agree with this. But I really like to have few questions here like "great RE beginners book?" Or "what is your RE toolbox?".
I'm aware that these type of questions are not really a SE Q&A questions, they usually consists of a big list of answers, and there's no real answer.
However, I find certain questions like these very good for beginners. I quite sure that everybody here once read a question like this in SO and found something interesting he didn't know before.
What do you think? Should we allow this ?

This has been discussed here http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-should-book-tutorial-questions-be-dealt-with/60#60 and somewhat described here -> http://meta.reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/96/lets-develop-a-tag-wiki-format

First a comment on the close votes. The question is certainly not off-topic here and on meta it is customary to use votes to voice agreement or disagreement. In fact a discussion like this one will only be stifled from closing the topic without discussing it.

@0xC0000022L Book, tutorial and tool questions have all either been discussed or are being discussed in other threads. The close votes are for closing as a duplicate of those threads. Any discussion should be done on those previously created posts.

@AshRj: fair enough. Although I would see this question as a superset of the other. But I get your point. Better to zoom in than zoom out for such topics.

I think this shouldn't be allowed in general and as I understand the tag wikis are meant to be used this way.
Problem with tag wikis is that a tag could go away at the whim of a moderator as far as I understand. Which would undo the work of many a volunteer.
Another issue is that tag wikis aren't as visible. They are mostly something people link to from answers. But why link to a tag wiki in the first place in an answer if questions that demand this kind of answer aren't allowed? If the tag wikis were visible and and could be searched and would be found via search engines, great. So far I have not seen a single search result going to a tag wiki on any SE site. It was always someone who dared to ask the question. It may have gotten closed, but the question is there to be found now.
So there is merit to asking those questions and also having them answered or at least having comments that point to the respective tag wiki.

Yes, visibility is a problem IMO. I for one never realized there's anything more than a simple summary behind the tags until the discussions here. If SE had a more traditional wiki format, with pages and categories and links, it would work better, but tag wikis are too limited.

Tim Post has asked for suggestions about Tag Wikis. You could suggest searchability as a feature request. The problem, if it exists, should be solved, not worked around.  Questions that ask these will be closed, there is no point in asking them.

@IgorSkochinsky Suggest visibility/searchability as a feature-request. Tim Post has asked for suggestions regarding Tag Wikis multiple times.

@AshRj: thanks for starting that topic :)

@0xC0000022L Sure :) I have to say though, I am not happy about  http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1754/beginners-books-on-microsoft-windows-software-reversing Its turning into a free for all.

@AshRj: I voted to close, as did you, I presume. The idea I had is outlined above. Make it CW, so anyone can edit and extend.
